# Корень слова "море"

Tags: этимология, морфемный-разбор

Ясно, что слово "море" происходит от латинского mare. А как называли море славяне?

Answer (score 6):

Слово *море* считается общеславянским. Исходно имело значение "какое-л.водное пространство" (в диалектах до сих пор фиксируется  значение "озеро"). Скорее всего, у него общеиндоевропейские корни, т.к. в других языках есть родственные слова: нем. *Meer* "море", готск. *marei* "море", нем. *Moor* "болото". Так что от латинского оно не происходит.

Answer (score 1):

В нашем русском языке есть однокоренные слова, сами говорящие о смысле предмета. Море, мороз, мор. Ни когда море не было для людей родной средой, как и мороз, полезным явлением...

Answer (score 0):

Море - исконное слово, происходит от ПИЕ ***moa̯ri*** "болото". С морозом, конечно, никак не связано.